# Adding ticks to axis (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following illustration in TikZ

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->,thick] (-4,0)--(4  ,0) node[right]{$F_T$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{asd}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I would like to add ticks to the axes at the points -4, -3, -2, …, 3, 4. The only labels I want are located at -4 and 4 and should say `A` at -4 and `B` at 4.

Is that possible somehow in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,thick] (-4.3,0)--(4.3,0) node[right]{$F_T$};
  \foreach \i in {-4,-3,...,4} \draw (\i,0)--(\i,.1);
  \node[below] at (-4,0) {$A$};
  \node[below] at (4,0) {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It will give you this:[image]